# Change bg-color on same element js function

Tags: javascript, background-color

I have a problem with changing background color on element.

```js
document.querySelector("#card1").addEventListener("click", changeBg);

function changeBg() {
  document.querySelector("#card1").style.background = "red";
}
```

```css
#card1 {
  display: block;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div id="card1">#card1</div>
```

Comment: and what exactly is that problem?

Comment: This script does not change the bg-color of the element.

Comment: `("click", changeBg())` <-- wrong || right --> `("click", changeBg)`

Comment: but it does change the background color. so what's the issue?